# Change the selected text in textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a custom text stylizer thingy... So if the user writes a text in the textarea, and selects a part of it, he would be able to use my custom "post-stylizer" buttons. Just like here, in Stackoverflow. Could someone help me with this, I've found nothing in this forums...

HTML

```
<div id="makeItBold" style="cursor: pointer;">B</div>    
<textarea id="text">I'm going to make THIS bold!</textarea>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#makeItBold").click(function() {

        if ($(this.selected).text().contains "<b>" or "</b>"){
            //if the selected text is already bolded, then remove it
            ???
        } else {
            //make it bold
            ???
            $(this.selected).text().replace(this.selected, "<b>" + this.selected + "</b>"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So you want to build a wysiwg editor? Like [this](http://ckeditor.com/download) one ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to toggle a css class on `#makeItBold` click using jquery , and give this css class `font-weight:bold`

add this Css class

```
.bold{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

and the use this jQuery function

```
 $('#makeItBold').click(function(){
      $('#text').toggleClass('bold');
    })
```

Check this link https://jsbin.com/devatejosu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: He wants to make the selection bold, not everything inside the textarea...